# How to save multiple lists into multiple rows in Pandas?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

So I have multiple lists that I would like to convert them to some soft of table format.

list1 has

```
1
2
3
```

list2 has

```
4
5
6
```

etc.

I would like to save this into a table format such as

```
list_1, list 2
1, 4
2, 5
3, 6
```

I've tried

```
col_a_c_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Column A and C', 'Column A and B and C', 'Column A and D and F', 'Column A and B and D and F'],
        data=[col_a_c, col_a_b_c, col_a_d_f, col_a_b_d_f])
col_a_c_df.to_csv("result.csv")
```

but it tells me that `ValueError: 4 columns passed, passed data had 17181 columns`

How do I do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can call DataFrame constructor after zipping both lists, where A, B represents column names and a, b are lists

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['A','B'], data=zip(a, b))
```

If lists are of uneven lengths

```
from itertools import zip_longest
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['A','B'], data=zip_longest(a, b)
```

Comment: Your solution is good, only possilbe simplify ;)

Comment: When I do this, it cuts off other datasets lengths. So every column has the same number of rows

Comment: Use this if your lists are of uneven lengths `list(itertools.zip_longest)` or check updated answer

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
list1 = [1,2,3]
list2 = [4,5,6]
df = pd.DataFrame({'list1': list1, 'list2': list2})

   list1 list2
0   1   4
1   2   5
2   3   6
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a reference example.

```
feature = ['Column A and C', 'Column A and B and C', 'Column A and D and F', 　　 'Column A and B and D and F']

data = np.array([
 [1,2,3],
 [4,5,6],
 [7,8,9],
 [10,11,12]
]).T

df = pd.DataFrame(data) 
df.columns = feature
print(df)
df.to_csv("result.csv")
```